# How do you assign array values to class member array in constructor, without using the std library?

Tags: c++, arrays

Trying to understand the proper way to copy values into an class member array. Currently, I take each value of the array and copy them into the corresponding element of the member array:

```
struct IPAddress
{
    IPAddress(const unsigned char values[4]) :
    values{values[0], values[1], values[2], values[3]}
    {
    }

    const unsigned char values[4];
};

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{

    unsigned char values[] = {10, 0, 0, 1};
    IPAddress address(values);
    return 0;
}
```

This works, but is there a way to "automagically" copy all the values in the constructor? I mean, what would I do if the values were of a class had 100 elements instead of 4? Or 1000?

I'm aware that I should be using `std::array`. But since this code is built for a microcontroller, using `std` library is not really an option.

Any takers?

Comment: Why can't you use a `std::array`- like class then? It's not hard to implement.

Comment: Don't use built-in arrays. There's no reason to.

Comment: `std::array` checks size of array at compiletime.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I'm aware that I should be using `std::array`. But since this code is built for a microcontroller, using `std` library is not really an option.

If you don't want to include `array`, you can still implement your own type for solving your issue:

```
template<typename T, std::size_t N>
class values_t {
public:
    values_t(const T *ptr) {
        // copy N elements
        for (std::size_t i = 0; i < N; ++i)
            value[i] = ptr[i]; // copy element
    }

    T& operator[](int i) { return value[i]; }
    const T& operator[](int i) const { return value[i]; }

private:
    typename std::remove_const<T>::type value[N];
};
```

Then, initializing the `values` data member of `IPAddress` becomes much simpler:

```
struct IPAddress
{
    IPAddress(const unsigned char values[4]) :
    values{values} {} // <-- copy as a whole

    values_t<const unsigned char, 4> values;
};
```

Answer (score 3):

You should be using `std::array`. This is one part of the standard library that shouldn't be offensive to embedded programming.

If you don't have access to it, it's not hard to implement a class just like it. It's a straight forward aggregate with saner semantics than raw arrays. It's also likely to be reused, which makes it a good candidate for a utility you *should* implement.

Failing that, you can rely on delegating c'tors, which I only add here for the intellectual exercise:

```
struct IPAddress
{
    IPAddress(const unsigned char values[4])
      : IPAddress(values, std::make_index_sequence<4>{})
    {
    }

    const unsigned char values[4];

private:
    template<std::size_t... I>
    IPAddress(const unsigned char values[4], std::index_sequence<I...>)
    : values{values[I]...}
    {
    }
};
```

The key is in the pack expansion `values{values[I]...}`, which turns into an initializer not unlike your original one. [**See it live**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/99ac13f3f2f180da).